# How to properly use start and stop timer on ASP.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, timer, code-behind

I am having problems on using a timer on ASP.Net
I am unable to start the timer after stopping it.

I am calling the functions from code behind using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "MyFun1", "startTimer();", true);
```

Gives me this error. Screenshot below..

[image]

My main problem is that I need to used the timer like this..
Do something > Start time > Do something on Tick + Stop time > Do something > Start time
But I can't because I cannot restart the timer when I stopped it.

```
<asp:Timer ID="tmrMain" runat="server" Interval="1000" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Timer>
```

Comment: Do you have jQuery properly loading?

Comment: not really good in web. But is it this one? I have this inside the <head> tag
`<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Because `$` is Jquery Object, `find` is method.

So you might use dot to call method

```
$.find('tmrMain');
```

Comment: Although .find function is there.. It throws different error. 

https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method '_stopTimer'

Comment: Could you Screenshot your error section or error section's code?